# Why is there an extra empty line after I print my output?

Tags: ruby, input, hash

I'm practicing some coding questions in Ruby on HackerRank and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting an extra empty line of output. The user input (from the console) is as follows:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

The first number tells you how many key value pairs there are that need to be added into a phoneBook hash. The next few lines (specified by the first number) are those key value pairs to be added. And the rest of the queries are the keys that I'm searching for. I've already written all of the code and I've tested it; it successfully adds the key value pairs into a hash named phoneBook and it also successfully prints the right values when I'm searching through the hash with the given keys. However, I'm getting an extra empty line of output at the end and I can't figure out why. Below is my code:

```
entries = []

num_entries = gets.to_i
num_entries.times do | input |
    entries << gets.chomp
end


phoneBook = {}
entries.each do | entry |
    str = entry.split
    phoneBook[str[0]] = str[1].to_i
end

name_str = gets.chomp
while name_str != ""
    if phoneBook.has_key?(name_str)
        puts name_str + "=" + phoneBook[name_str].to_s
    else
        puts "Not found"
    end

    name_str = gets.chomp
end
```

And this is the error message that I'm receiving:

```
Solution.rb:23:in `<main>': undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I understand that the error is probably coming from trying to execute code on that blank line of output that I'm getting, but I thought that once the user input is blank, it'll exit out of the while loop.

Comment: I don't understand how you could get that exception. In your code `chomp`'s receiver is always `gets`, but `gets` (as used here) cannot return `nil`, only a string, even if it contains only a newline character. What is the value of your global variable `$stdin`? (I expect `#<IO:<STDIN>>`.) btw, `str` is perhaps not the best name for an array. :-) (Maybe `arr = entry.split`.)

Comment: Please answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name_str = gets.chomp
```

In the HackerEarth website, the input is read from a file. When there is no input to be read from the file, the gets returns a nil object. As the nil does not have a chomp method(Restricted to classes like string), the exception is thrown.

1. A quick fix for the code can be a to_s method after the gets statement.

```
gets.to_s.chomp
```

2. A better fix, IMO would be to read the inputs till nil is received.

```
until((name_str = gets.chomp).nil?)
  name_str.chomp!
  # Rest of the logic
end
```

Comment: Thanks! For number 2, is name_str being "chomped" twice? I'm a bit confused on why we need to chomp name_str again in the loop :(

Comment: And I tried the first way, but it seems that either there's an infinite loop or the code takes too long to execute.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in 2. The condition is name_str = gets, no chomp in the conditional. For the first option, to_s just converts the object to a string. So nil should become '', computationally it should not take that much time. There is no print observed in the console for to_s fix, is it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by, "When there is no input to be read from the console...". Does `gets` (when used without arguments) not wait patiently for a newline (possibly preceded by other characters) to be entered?

Comment: In HackerRank Website, the input would be a file from which the data is read. At the end of the file, gets would return a nil. If the name of the file is stored in ARGV and the gets is used, then it would read line by line and return nil at the last line. Does that answer the question?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the relevant part of the HankerRank site? I don’t doubt what you are saying but the OP says nothing about `gets` taking input from a file rather than from the console.

Comment: Okay, sure! The link is https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/  In that section, in any problem there would be an online ide. Using gets in that ide would read from the input file.